# Constant Density of States and Perturbation theory

Tags: condensed-matter, perturbation-theory, greens-functions

Given a constant Density of States (DOS) corresponding to a one-electron hamiltonian, $\text{DOS}(\omega)=\dfrac{1}{2D} \chi_{[-D,D ]}(\omega),$ where $\chi$ is the indicator function, I want to know what is its corresponding **causal** Green Function. The retarded Green function can be seen to be:
$$G^R(\omega)=\int \dfrac{\text{DOS}(\omega^\prime)}{\omega-\omega^\prime+i\eta}d\omega^\prime,$$ and doing this integral took me to:
$$G^R(\omega)= \dfrac{1}{4D}\log \left[ \dfrac{(\omega-D)^2+\eta^2}{(\omega+D)^2+\eta^2} \right]+\dfrac{i}{2D} \left[ \text{atan} \left( \dfrac{\omega-D}{\eta} \right)-\text{atan} \left( \dfrac{\omega+D}{\eta} \right) \right].$$

I obtained the advanced Green function by replacing $i\eta$ by $-i\eta.$

My problem is the following: **I want to perform perturbation theory at zero temperature to compute the self-energy, the Green function and the DOS, but the Green function I need to plug into the Feynman diagrams is the causal one**. How can I find it? Or how can I, alternatively, do perturbation theory with these objects?

Comment: What exactly you want to calculate perturbatively? Free energy or some correlation functions? Are you working at zero temperature?

Comment: Is zero temperature and what I want to calculate is the green function o self-energy. Actually the DOS. In any case, I want to understand what is the causal Green function in this problem. Thanks!

Comment: For time ordered correlator in this case you would have in the integrand something like $\frac{\theta(\omega'-\mu)}{\omega-\omega'+i\eta}+\frac{\theta(\mu-\omega')}{\omega-\omega'-i\eta}$. In any case, you should cross check it against Mahan/AGD/Fetter-Walecka.